# Where is the code of a new view i've created?

Tags: 7, views, blocks, theming

i'm using drupal 7 with starter theme of zen. i've created a view on a block, now i need to customize some parts of `html / css` in order to add just media query (css part) and add a `<a>` tag with `display:none` for desktop version and `display:block` for mobile. SO i need to modify html AND css of this view. I'm searching for the php file of this view and i didn't find it.

Any help please ?

Comment: It's dynamic, the rendered content isn't actually saved anywhere except a transient cache if you have that enabled. For the customisations you've outlined, you don't need to make any HTML changes, just CSS, so just use your theme's CSS file

Comment: You can find the appropriate file name for the template in the right part of your view's interface: click on *Theme* and you'll see the activated templates.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the Theming link in the Advanced tab, you will get a list of possible template files that you can use. See here:
[image: Views Theming - Information Tab]

Next, you can click on "Display Output" to get a copy of the PHP that is powering the view. See here: 
[image: Views Theming - Display Output]

Copy that PHP into a file and save it using the naming pattern of your choice from the list beside "Display Output".

Click on "Rescan template files" to make your theme aware of the new template.

Now, any changes you make to that template - add CSS classes, etc - will automatically be picked up.

If you wish to edit HTML for the style or row, just click on the relevant "Style Output" or "Row Style Output" link instead of "Display Output".

I hope this helps you.